# sed command - find and replace while excluding specific pattern in find

Tags: regex, unix, replace, sed, find

I have a specific case with sed.

As part of the build process, we are required to find and replace the version numbers of required artifacts with the newly created tag name across multiple modules (pom.xml) files.

The command we use is this:

`find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/6\.0\.0\.0/6.0.0.0.001/g'`

The edge case we have is this:

There are some modules that have similar version numbers but are already frozen versions coming in from our repository. These need not be changed.

Entries such as `<modulename-version>modulename-6.0.0.0.016</modulename-version>` are present in the pom.xml's but do not need to be changed.

Is there a way to ignore a pattern of `6\.0\.0\.0\.\d{3}` with sed?

The entire setup is intended to run un-attended via python-fabric on our remote build server and we really dont want to wake up in the night to try and solve a problem where a module `modulename-6.0.0.0.001.016.jar` was not found!

Any help in this space would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your sed command to:

```
'/6\.0\.0\.0\.\d{3}/!s/6\.0\.0\.0/6.0.0.0.001/g'
```

Or

```
'/6\.0\.0\.0\.\d{3}/b; s/6\.0\.0\.0/6.0.0.0.001/g'
```

Sed may also not accept `\d`, so you can just use `[0-9]`:

```
'/6\.0\.0\.0\.[0-9]{3}/!s/6\.0\.0\.0/6.0.0.0.001/g'
```

`{3}` also may need `-r`

```
`sed -r ...`
```

Complete commands:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ri '/6\.0\.0\.0\.[0-9]{3}/!s/6\.0\.0\.0/6.0.0.0.001/g'

find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ri '/6\.0\.0\.0\.[0-9]{3}/b; s/6\.0\.0\.0/6.0.0.0.001/g'
```

Comment: @cruisemaniac Just want to verify. Your lines contain only one version string each right?

Comment: So far, yes. Will the /g operator not take care of multiple replacements on the same line?

Comment: Well the thing is the pattern `6\.0\.0\.0\.[0-9]{3}` would make sed skip processing the whole line even if only a single version gets to match it.

Comment: ah! I did not know this. But since the scenario in the question is in and by itself an edge-case scenario, we'll have to live with it I guess. And I'll have to tell the devs to re-arrange the codebase so it doesnt create problems like you mentioned!